# latexmk cd option not working

Tags: latexmk

I'm using latexmk to build my latex files. The command `latexmk -cd E:\work\foo.tex` used to work fine until I updated my latexmk to ver 4.41 using texlive's tlmgr, and suddenly the -cd option's no longer working: it says "no such file or directory" and quits. I can manually cd to the directory and latexmk works fine there, but I've been using a script to call it from a gui (e.g. sublimetext). If I remove the -cd option it will build in the sublime program directory which is not what I want. How to fix that?

Comment: There is indeed a problem.  One bug with the `-cd` option was fixed in the newly released v. 4.41 of latexmk, but the fix caused another bug which I didn't detect.  Until I correct the problem, I suggest reverting to v. 4.39, which can be obtained at http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/versions.html

Comment: @david: +1. In the meantime, I put a `cd` in my script before the `latexmk`. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: @Ramashalanka I got in touch with the author of latexmk (John Collins) and he had a bug-fix. Wait for 4.42 or as John Collins suggested, revert to 4.39 for the time being.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Anyway, 4.42 is available now and seems to fix the problem.